# libvlc displays wrong washed out colors with HDR videos

Tags: vlc, codec, libvlc, hdr, vlc-android

I was integrating libvlc into my project and found out that when I was playing an HDR video it showed washed-out colors. Later I built my own debug version of vlc-android to compare it to the release version in Google Play but the colors were correct in the applications. In conclusion:

- If I build vlc-android and play the video in the application, no problem.
- If I build libvlc and set default media options (HW decode enabled), wrong colors.
- If I build libvlc and disable HW decoding, right colors but frame drops.

I've check logs with codec and color information and there was no difference.
So did I miss something to configure?

[image: vlc-android]

[image: demo with libvlc]

Comment: inspect libvlc options used by vlc-android

Comment: in fact I've already inspected libvlc options and none of them worked as I expected. the strange thing is that when I built the vlc-android application the color was correct. but with libvlc + my test application, the color was wrong. I even removed the libvlc and media options in vlc-android application but the color was still working properly

Comment: your libvlc build is probably wrong then

Comment: but what's the difference? 'compile.sh -a arm64 -l -r', and I've checked the package at the maven repository and even that was wrong too.

Comment: try extracting the .so files from the vlc-android APK and see if you reproduce the issue in your app.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that before too and nothing changed

Comment: if the same libvlc build works in vlc-android but not in your app, I guess it has to do with libvlc configuration. reach out for commercial support if you're interested cause I'm out of time and ideas right now.